# Succinct CSV complete file read using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a csv file with n different columns, an example is attached below. How can I output the entire csv file using an awk (to be used by a dbms using STDIN). I've tried

```
awk -v RS='\r\n' '{print $1 ',' $1 + 1} file
```

but this wraps around causing the first column to also be printed at the end. Also is there a way to change the file ending when reading the csv so that it outputs in the form '\r\n'. Preferably looking for a one-liner.

```
1, 20, Is
2, 12, this
3, 18, minimal
4, 21, enough
```

and the output should be

```
1, 20, Is
2, 12, this
3, 18, minimal
4, 21, enough
```

printed in terminal with line breaks and commas in the same position using `awk` (no `cat`).

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have some reason for doing this so....

Robustly with GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
awk -v BINMODE=3 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\r\n"} 1' file
```

BINMODE (see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Built_002din-Variables) is required because on some platforms the underlying C primitives consume the line-ending `\r`s before gawk gets to see them.

idk how you'd deal with that BINMODE-requiring situation with a POSIX awk but if awk is seeing the `\r`s and assuming you don't have any `\n`s in the middle of your records (e.g. as you would when exporting a spreadsheet that includes cells that span multiple lines from MS-Excel) then in any awk:

```
awk '1' file
```

If you have fields that contain newlines and for more information generally on DOS line endings and parsing CSVs with awk see:

- [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it)
- [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk)